# HP-G64-455SX not detecting the webcam

Tags: 11.10, hardware, webcam

I have a *HP-G64-455SX* laptop.

Windows was corrupted so I decided to install Ubuntu 11.10 on it. All things were working properly but my webcam is not working.

Last time I used my webcam was 3 weeks ago.

How do I fix this error I have googled a lot but didn't find anything?

Here is the `lspci` output:

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)    
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

Here the `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:1000 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

Comment: unless I'm missing something... I cant see the webcam in that list - possibly a USB device?  what is the output of `lsusb`.  Note - on some laptops there is a Fn key type arrangement to enable a webcam.  If you dont use this, the O/S doesnt see the webcam.

Comment: updated.........no function like this

Comment: ... well your connected usb devices dont correspond to webcams either.  Since lsusb and lspci see hardware level stuff - I dont see in your trace logs a physical webcam on your laptop.  Are you sure you havent got a hardware switch/slider to enable your webcam?

Comment: its buitin cam ...just like in every laptop ...& no other option to on/off cam ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it is a hardware problem.

Thanks to fossfreedom!